# Writing my own 'TreeMap' class - what to extend and/or implement?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, treemap

For an assignment, I have been asked to "Create a class called `TreeMap` that uses the `BinarySearchTree` class to implement a map". We are given a collection of interfaces and classes to extend and implement.

The first step of the assignment asks to "Create an inner class called `TreeEntry` to store the entries. Include a constructor and any mandatory methods".

The interfaces we are given include `BinaryTree<T>`, `Entry<K, V>`, `Map<K, V>` and more.

A class we are given is `BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T>` and many more.

I am struggling to determine how to declare my `TreeMap`. Should it extend `BinarySearchTree`, or implement `Map`, or both?

So far, what I have come up with is `public class TreeMap<K, V> implements Map<Comparable<K>, V>` and will then create the `TreeMap` nested class, but then I do not see where I would "use the `BinarySearchTree` class to implement the map"? Do I create a new `BinarySearchTree<TreeEntry<K, V>>` inside my `TreeMap` class?

**EDIT**

This is what I have written so far:

```
public class TreeMap<K, V> implements Map<Comparable<K>, V> {

    private class TreeEntry<K, V> implements Entry<K, V>, Comparable<K> {

        private K key;
        private V value;

        public TreeEntry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(K otherKey) {
            if (this.key.equals(otherKey)) {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (this.key > otherKey) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

I believe I am not implementing `Comparable<K>` correctly as I am getting an error for the line `else if (this.key > otherKey)` saying that `The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) K, K`

Comment: I would assume that if you have been given a class you are expected to use it. How you do that depends on how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the BinarySearchTree as an implementation is currently an assignment. It could be your current idea or somebody's suggestion on how to do it. If you inherit from it and at a later point, when thousands of customers use your TreeMap and you decide that BinarySearchTree is not the perfect implementation, then you will not be able to change it anymore.

This is because somebody might have used it as

```
BinarySearcTree<X,Y> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Now what? You're stuck with your inheritance of BinarySearchTree. But if you "only" implement Map, then you can at any time change the implementation of the class without causing problems to clients.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have begun writing my implementation following what you have outlined, but there is a problem with making the Keys in my `TreeMap` comparable. See my edit in the original post.

Comment: java doesn't have any operator overloading. so you cannot define the operator ">" for your key class. The java way to do this is to implement Comparable and implement the compareTo method. Then you can do public int compareTo(K other) {return this.key.compareTo(other.key);}